# how to set cookie in new window?

Tags: javascript, cookies, window.open

I want to open new window by using window.open and I want to set new cookie for that new window . 
I have tried to set cookie by using below code

```
        window.open("https://mysite.n")
        var expires = (function(days){
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 
                   1000));
                 return date.toUTCString();
           })(5);
      document.cookie ="mytestcookie=testcookie; expires="+expires+"; path=/";
```

After this code execution . When I tried to get this cookie in new window I am getting undefined . Please help to set cookie in new window .

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the cookie **before** you load the new page. Just reorder your code so `window.open` is last.

This assumes that new page is on the same origin as the current page. If it isn't, you can't set a cookie. It would be a major security problem if you could record data in a datastore belonging to someone else's website.

Comment: the new page in not on the same origin . I agree that someone else's website , but that is the need currently we have , so is it possible to set cookie in new window ?

Comment: @silvesterprabu — No. If it was possible, it would be a massive security problem. Your need does not trump that. Find some other way to pass your data to the third party site. You'll need their cooporation.

Comment: if subdomain is same then is it possible to set cookie ?

Comment: @silvesterprabu That dependes on how the cookie domain is set. But yes you can do that and cookies will be accessible if the subdomain is same. e.g. app1.sub1.example.com and app2.sub2.example.com can access cookies set with domain example.com and path /

Answer (score 0):

Quentin is absolutely right, but there is a way if you really have to achieve this just use a Headless Chromium with for example Puppeteer. You can go to the page and afterwords set the Cookies.